# What code controls the animation for the front-page header in TwentySeventeen

Tags: frontpage

I'm struggling in finding the code that initiates the animation process for the header front page of Twentyseventeen.  I would like to see it.

All I know is that when the animation is over, it adds an inline attribute of `margin-bottom:....` on the following elements: `.custom-header` and `.site-branding`

I'm on wordpress 4.9.2

Thanks for any tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to be global.js, in the `adjustHeaderHeight()` function at lines 92 - 97

```
// The margin should be applied to different elements on front-page or home vs interior pages.
if ( isFrontPage ) {
    $branding.css( 'margin-bottom', navigationOuterHeight );
} else {
    $customHeader.css( 'margin-bottom', navigationOuterHeight );
}
```

It sets the margin-bottom to the equivalent of the top navigation menu's "outerHeight" (as defined and measured earlier) and seems to be based on the assumption that you're probably going to have a 1 line menu that will be 70px tall, since the theme CSS is for a 70px bottom margin. The script overrules that setting.

If you have no top menu, then site-branding transitions 70px (to 0 margin-bottom) in .2 seconds (`.site-branding {transition: margin-bottom 0.2s}` (shortened)).

Oddly, the measure for outerHeight is on my default testing installation 72px - so there's a 2px jitter after I add a short menu. On multi-line menus it starts to have problems with overlap.

Anyway, I've never looked at this before, but it doesn't strike me as one of Twenty Seventeen's better worked-out capacities. Maybe the designer/developers just liked the animation effect that the default installation - prior to creation of any top menus - shows.